# Recovery data after formatting data after testdisk and photorec provided poor results

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery

I have two disks with files that I manually mirror with rsync. The disks are two 1TB external usb disks (disk A, disk B). Sometimes I put some files only on one disk when I feel that I do not need to have backup to save some space.
Now I mistakenly formatted disk B by some utility and I have some files I would like to have back from disk B.

I used few nice linux utilities:

Step 1: I used **testdisk** to recover the partition (ntfs) but in one step I choose to recover MTF from backup and it was wrong choice. I lost the MTF completely (it contains metadata about files on disk, where they are, etc.)

Step 2: I used **photorec** to recover files. Photorec is searching on the disk and looking at the headers of the files and possibily recover them.
I selected in photorec to recover all filetypes I found usable, but just some crap was recovered. I have some dd images there I'd like to have back. Biggest file that was recovered has 63 MB. Doh.

Any idea what could I try next?

I have some files on disk A that are also on disk B, so is there any tool that can mark those same blocks on disk B for me?

Related question:
[How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with Autopsy http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/

This application allows you to inspect NTFS partition after you have partial quick reformat. It shows file paths, folders and you are one click away from extracting the whole directories.